# jquery click event works for dynamic content on desktop browsers but not mobile browsers

Tags: jquery

I have this following code for the dynamically loaded content, which works on desktop browsers but not on mobile devices.

First I call the dynamic content like this,which adds the items i want/order to a list:

**this works on mobile**

```
<script>
    $('document').ready(function(){
        $('li p').click(function(){
            $('#ordered').load('cart.php?action=add&id='+this.id);
    });
</script>
```

the list shows the item name,price,qty and an option to remove item from list. the code to remove goes like this:

**this does not work on mobile**

```
<script>
    $('document').ready(function(){

    $('.r').bind('click',function(){
        $('#ordered').load('cart.php?action=delete&id='+this.id);

    });});
</script>
```

Thanks

**EDIT**

I got my solution. I had to use `live()` function as i had been calling elements dynamically and its working fine. Sorry, my bad. :P  Any ways thank you all. :)

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use [JQueryMobile](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html) for the tap events. Clicks don't always work on touch screen

Just as an idea - you can chain the event handlers and handle click, taps, swipes etc.. together i.e.

```
function myClickHandler (e)
{
   //.. do work
}

$('li p').bind('click',myClickHandler)
          .bind('tap', myClickHandler)
          .bind('swipe', myClickHandler);
```

Therefore it is possible to cover off all kind of events at once. From JQuery 1.7 on you would use `on` not `bind`

Might help

Comment: but my other onclick events are working fine on my mobile device. these $('document').ready(function(){
 $('#ordered').draggable();
  $('li p').click(function(){
   $('#ordered').load('cart.php?action=add&id='+this.id);
  });
  
  $('.details').click(function(){
   //alert(this.id);
   $('#details').load('details.php?detail_id='+this.id);
   
  });
  
  $('#categories ul li').click(function(){
   $('#booklist').load('db.php?id='+this.id);
  });
 }); works properly.

Comment: any ways i'll try chaining events and try will let you know.